# Windows service Application.LocalUserAppDataPath

Tags: windows-service

Application.LocalUserAppDataPath" is differ from "Application.CommonAppDataPath" for a same windows service? The "Application.LocalUserAppDataPath" suppose to refer the same path as "Application.CommonAppDataPath".

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is by design.  It's the way the OS is intended to work.